# Is this kind of functor $\mathsf{Set}/M×\mathsf{Set}/M\to \mathsf{Set}/M$, with $M$ a monoid, a known construction?

Tags: ct.category-theory, computer-science

I'm trying to construct lists with elements of type $A$ as the initial algebra over a base endofunctor in $\mathsf{Set}/\mathcal{P}(A)$, such that the list is indexed by the set of its elements.

My idea is to model `Cons` using a bifunctor $C\colon\ \mathsf{Set}/\mathcal{P}(A)\times\mathsf{Set}/\mathcal{P}(A)\to \mathsf{Set}/\mathcal{P}(A)$.

My definition of $C$ would be $C_0 (X,f) (Y,g) := (X\times Y, \lambda(a,b).\,f(a)\cup g(b))$.

My List base functor would then be $L_0(R,r) := (1,\lambda\_.\,\emptyset ) + C_0\left(\left(A,\lambda x.\,\{x\}\right),\left(R,r\right)\right)$.

My question is: Is this kind of bifunctor $C$ a known construction? I find what it does reminiscent of the $\mu$ (join) of the [Action Monad](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/action+monad) (aka Writer monad), but can't quite put my finger on it.

Comment: Note that the TeX rendering of commands might be different from a Unicode character with the same meaning: compare $\lambda λ$ `\lambda λ` and $\mu μ$ `\mu μ`.  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: @LSpice Different doesn't mean worse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, for any monoidal category $(\mathcal M, \otimes, I)$ and a monoid $(m, *, i) \in \mathcal M$, the [slice category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/over+category#examples) $\mathcal M/m$ inherits the monoidal structure pointwise, i.e. the tensor product is given by taking morphisms $f : x \to m$ and $g : y \to m$ to the morphism $x \otimes y \xrightarrow{f \otimes g} m \otimes m \xrightarrow{*} m$, and the unit is given by $i : I \to m$.

In your example, we take $(\mathbf{Set}, \times, 1)$ to be the category of sets equipped with [cartesian monoidal structure](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cartesian+monoidal+category) and $(m, *, i)$ to be the power set monoid $(\mathcal P A, \cup, \varnothing)$.

Abstractly, we can see resulting tensor product on $\mathbf{Set}/\mathcal{P}A$ to be given by the following composite

$$(\mathbf{Set}/\mathcal{P}A)^2 \simeq (\mathbf{Set}^{\mathcal{P}A})^2 \xrightarrow{\langle-,-\rangle} (\mathbf{Set}^2)^{({\mathcal{P}A}^2)} \xrightarrow{\times^{({\mathcal{P}A}^2)}} \mathbf{Set}^{({\mathcal{P}A}^2)} \simeq \mathbf{Set}/({\mathcal{P}A}^2) \xrightarrow{\mathbf{Set}/\cup} \mathbf{Set}/{\mathcal{P}A}$$

where the equivalences are given by the correspondence between indexed sets and $\mathbf{Set}$-functors from discrete categories.

The unit is given similarly by

$$1 \xrightarrow{1} \mathbf{Set} \simeq \mathbf{Set}/1 \xrightarrow{\mathbf{Set}/i} \mathbf{Set}/{\mathcal{P}A}$$

Comment: Is this equivalent to taking the product $(x,f) × (y,g)$ in the arrow category $\mathcal{M}^→$ and then applying the left base change functor $*_!$ to it?

Comment: @cxandru: could you clarify what you mean by the left base change? What are the domain and codomain of the functor?

Comment: I think I mean $∗_!:(\mathcal{M}/m⊗m)→\mathcal{M}/m$, defined as $∗!(z,h)=(z,∗∘h)$, if $*$ has type $m⊗m→m$

Comment: The tensor product is given by a composite $\mathcal M/m \times \mathcal M/m \to \mathcal M^2/(m, m) \to \mathcal M/(m \otimes m) \to \mathcal M/m$, where the last functor is the one you mention. However, it's not possible to express this in terms of the arrow category, because we need to only consider morphisms with certain codomains (e.g. $m$).

Comment: Is there a way to construct this composite without using the indexed sets correspondence? I don't want to introduce too much background. Sorry for all the back & forth. I'm using this construction in my Master's thesis btw, I've added your answer here as a citation

Comment: I found [reference request - Non-Cartesian Monoidal Model Structure on a Slice Category - MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/229358/non-cartesian-monoidal-model-structure-on-a-slice-category) this question where the first answer seems to mention this construction as well but there doesn't seem to be a clear reference for it in literature

Comment: This is definitely a well known construction (e.g. see this [nLab entry](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+topos#SliceToposOverAMonoidObject)), but I'm afraid I don't know a reference in the literature for it...

Comment: You don't need to present the monoidal structure via the indexing: I just mentioned that as another way to see the structure. The easiest way to present the monoidal structure is abstractly, as I did in the first paragraph.